# The figure/(table name) is on the page header by use fancyhdr, How to solve it?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

[image]

The is black line is page header line.

`\usepackage{fancyhdr}`

`\usepackage{cctbook}` in the preamble.

`\pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhead[CE]{\songti 一维二维}\fancyhead[CO]{\songti   为了部落}`

I insert the figure or table by used `\begin{table\figure}[H] \end{table\figure}` environment.

Comment: Increase \headheight to fit the header (using the geometry package).

Comment: Thanks，I know the problem by your answer.